# Why are commerce_* permissions disabled when generating System User token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm a dev on an integration project. I have **ZERO** Graph experience and I'm blocked, have been blocked for days trying to get through the [API Integration Setup document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/setup/api-setup). As I've worked through each step of the document I've asked the client for what I think are the permissions or access I need. They've cooperated and I've managed to make it through most of the document' steps. I'm confident once we get through this administrative stage of gaining access I'll be fine.

Specifically on the last task in Step #5

> "Start with calling the commerce_orders API endpoint to list the details of the order that you placed in your shop on Facebook"

When I make the specified API call:

```
curl -X GET -G \
  -d 'state="IN_PROGRESS"' \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE-ID}/commerce_orders
```

I receive the error:

> "(#200) Application does not have required permission commerce_account_read_orders, commerce_account_manage_orders or the capability to make this API call. In case of permissions, your app must be live and have approved permissions for accessing regular shop."

That's pretty clear! Now the challenge is knowing how to resolve it. I went through the steps of generating an Access Token for the system user once again, and sure enough I see the permissions mentioned in the error are listed, un-selected and disabled (see below screenshot)

[image].

The required permissions are:

1. commerce_account_manage_orders
2. commerce_account_read_orders
3. commerce_manage_accounts

Finally to my question: What should I request of my client to correct this lacking permission issue? As a facebook and Graph API newb, I don't know where to begin with my request and I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

Regards,
Steve

Comment: any update here? we are facing the same issue

Comment: No. The client is considering aborting the project because they can't get any help from FB either. If you do figure it out, please try to come back here and comment or answer, for my sake.

Comment: no, unable to resolve

Comment: Same here. Project cancelled. Facebook sounds like they're absolutely terrible to work with.